Why is robot model collapsing in gazebo even with controller settings?
I am currently working with Ros Noetic, Gazebo, and Moveit. I have converted a KUKA lbr iiwa CAD model to a URDF (kuka_model_0) and made modifications to the package.xml, CmakeLists.txt, and the URDF file itself by implementing transmission tags, self collision tags. I also wrote a .yaml file to define ROS controllers for the seven different joints including publishing joint states.
However, when launching the gazebo.launch file, the model is collapsing despite having set controllers. Looking like this:

Here is the code of the robot's model urdf file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.6.0-4-g7f85cfe  Build Version: 1.6.7995.38578
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->
<robot
  name="kuka_model_0">
  
  <link name="world"/>
  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>
  
  <link
    name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.012837 8.2503E-07 0.070107"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="3.8629" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.014225"
        ixy="1.2748E-07"
        ixz="0.00061283"
        iyy="0.017765"
        iyz="-4.6349E-08"
        izz="0.016962" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link
    name="link_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-5.4919E-07 -0.034732 0.11351"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.7025" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.017086"
        ixy="-1.2424E-09"
        ixz="1.3708E-07"
        iyy="0.0163"
        iyz="0.003042"
        izz="0.0060293" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_1"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 0.1575"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="link_1" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-2.96706"
      upper="2.96706"
      effort="176"
      velocity="1.71" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="link_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="3.0897E-07 -0.067328 0.034415"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.7258" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.017049"
        ixy="1.1151E-07"
        ixz="-7.2318E-08"
        iyy="0.0060958"
        iyz="-0.0028369"
        izz="0.016245" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_2.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_2.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_2"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 -0.0005 0.183"
      rpy="-1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_1" />
    <child
      link="link_2" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-2.0944"
      upper="2.0944"
      effort="176"
      velocity="1.71" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="link_3">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="3.6273E-07 0.029563 0.1265"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="3.1751" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.025078"
        ixy="-5.1735E-08"
        ixz="-1.5753E-07"
        iyy="0.023807"
        iyz="-0.0048733"
        izz="0.007608" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_3.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_3.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_3"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 -0.184 0"
      rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_2" />
    <child
      link="link_3" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-2.96706"
      upper="2.96706"
      effort="110"
      velocity="1.74" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="link_4">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-3.5093E-07 -0.067328 -0.034415"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.7259" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.017049"
        ixy="-1.1039E-07"
        ixz="-1.3786E-07"
        iyy="0.0060959"
        iyz="0.0028369"
        izz="0.016245" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_4.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_4.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_4"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0.0005 0.2155"
      rpy="-1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_3" />
    <child
      link="link_4" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-2.0944"
      upper="2.0944"
      effort="110"
      velocity="2.27" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="link_5">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-2.4335E-07 0.021386 0.075466"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="1.6938" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.010079"
        ixy="-3.0203E-08"
        ixz="-3.1739E-08"
        iyy="0.0087026"
        iyz="-0.0030904"
        izz="0.0044694" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_5.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_5.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_5"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 -0.184 0"
      rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_4" />
    <child
      link="link_5" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-2.96706"
      upper="2.96706"
      effort="110"
      velocity="2.44" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="link_6">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="1.5372E-06 -0.0021201 -0.060489"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="1.8367" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0050944"
        ixy="-3.9896E-08"
        ixz="6.1032E-08"
        iyy="0.0035427"
        iyz="0.0002496"
        izz="0.004899" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_6.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_6.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_6"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0.0607 0.2155"
      rpy="-1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_5" />
    <child
      link="link_6" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-2.0944"
      upper="2.0944"
      effort="40"
      velocity="3.14" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="link_7">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.00041041 0.00024735 0.028447"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.40315" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00036374"
        ixy="3.7747E-07"
        ixz="4.6864E-06"
        iyy="0.00036526"
        iyz="-2.7816E-07"
        izz="0.0004725" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_7.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://kuka_model_0/meshes/link_7.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint_7"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 -0.0804 -0.060014"
      rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="link_6" />
    <child
      link="link_7" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.05433"
      upper="3.05433"
      effort="40"
      velocity="3.14" />
  </joint>
  
  <transmission name="link_1_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_1">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_1_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  
  <transmission name="link_2_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_2">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_2_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  
  <transmission name="link_3_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_3">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_3_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  
  <transmission name="link_4_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_4">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_4_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>

  <transmission name="link_5_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_5">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_5_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  
  <transmission name="link_6_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_6">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_6_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  
  <transmission name="link_7_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_7">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_7_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  
  
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
        <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo reference="link_1">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo reference="link_2">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo reference="link_3">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo reference="link_4">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo reference="link_5">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo reference="link_6">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo reference="link_7">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  </gazebo>
  
  
</robot>


and here is the code of the joint_trajectory_controller.yaml:
#Controller to control robot arm joints
robot_arm_controller:
  type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
  joints: [joint_1, joint_2, joint_3, joint_4, joint_5, joint_6, joint_7]

#Controller to continuously publish joint states/positions
joint_state_controller:
  type: "joint_state_controller/JointStateController"
  publish_rate: 50

Why is the launching not succeeding? What can be done to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.
Same goes with the moveit simulation where I can plan the poses but not execute them in gazebo.
I run the following to see the list of controllers:

rosservice info /controller_manager/list_controllers

But getting the following as output:

ERROR: unknown service

P.S.: I am new to the ROS, gazebo framework so please bare with me :).
